# jquery how to add pin to image and save the position to SQL

Tags: jquery, sql, image

How can I pin an image, and save the position of my pins?

I found [this plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/uKkRh/1/), but I don't know how to save the position of these pins.

The idea is like Google Map, where the user can put as many pin as he likes, and save these pin positions into database;  the next time he logs in, he could see where he put his pin.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - its pretty simple but works well.

http://duncanheron.github.com/dropPin/

You will need to customise it for your needs, but the general idea for adding pin co-ordinates to an image is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get nodes information like this:

```
function getNodes(){
    var nodes = [];
    $('img', $('#container')).each(function(){
        nodes.push([$(this).css('top'), $(this).css('left')]);
    });

    $.post('save.php', {nodes: nodes}, function(data){}, 'json');
}
```

Then the position of the nodes will be post to save.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery mouse position to know where you've added a pin and shove these vars into your sql database.

```
$("#special").click(function(e){
      $('#imgId').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   });
```

The tricky part is getting the jquery vars to php (Resources below)
so you're sql should look something similar like this:

user_id - pin_id - positionX - positionY

**Resources:**

**Mouse position:** http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

**Passing jquery to php:** http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?650046-Passing-Jquery-Var-To-Php-Mysql-Query

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT DUE TO FIRST COMMENT ON THIS POST:**

You can simply add a new image when you click and give it a style along with it just like this:

```
$("#imageDiv").click(function (e) {
     $(this).addImage($(this), e.pageX, e.pageY);
});


function addImage(object, xPos, yPos){
     object.append("<img src='markerImg.png' style='position:absolute; left:"+xPos+";   top:"+yPos";' />");     
}
```

**PS: your object div should be set to position: relative & not sure if this will work, this is written without testing the code, some changes may be needed!**