# django admin points to image

Tags: jquery, python, django

Sorry if my question is a little broad, having an issue even searching for what i need.

In essence, I have a hero image in the django admin, but I need to create a custom form that allows placing points onto the image (like a map, but not a map).

I am at a complete loss as to how to do this within the confines of the admin framework.  I believe my question is (kindof) similar to this:  [jquery how to add pin to image and save the position to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616035/jquery-how-to-add-pin-to-image-and-save-the-position-to-sql)

But specifically regarding django admin integration.

EDIT:

I'll most likely use either http://pictip.greenmandarine.net/  or http://duncanheron.github.io/dropPin/

So, really, my question is how to coerce Django admin to display a master image and allow the user to click points and save those points to a db.  Note:  I'm not a first time django user, so I get the ORM, this is more of how to mess with django admin with a custom form to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add custom JS + Form

You can inject arbitrary scripts into an admin by using the form class `meta Media` class OR `ModelAdmin.Media`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

You can build custom forms to accept arbitrary information ( `this_field_doesn't_actually_exist = forms.CharField`).

You can add methods from the `ModelAdmin` by adding the method name to any parameter that accepts form fields, and by adding that method name to `readonly_fields`

E.g.

```
readonly_fields = ('foo', )
fields = ('foo',)
def foo(self, obj):
    return "Arbtrary HTML"
foo.allow_tags = True
```

Now you have

- An HTML image
- Arbitrary javascript
- Arbitrary form fields to pass to python

### Add custom widget

As a commenter suggested, [you can build widgets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets) or a [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) which know how to render itself (including adding of extra media, display of input, and parsing return values, and converting values for storage in the case of model fields), but I've found it relatively complex if you need multiple inputs.

Research this method if you want to build something you will re-use in many places.

### You can also override the admin templates per model

You can also override some templates per-model. This can be a cleaner method, depending on how much customization you want to do.

Personally, I'd do JS + readonly_field until I *really* need to customize the form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

#### You can also specify custom paths per modeladmin:

> ModelAdmin.add_form_template Path to a custom template, used by
> add_view().
>
> ModelAdmin.change_form_template Path to a custom template, used by
> change_view().
>
> ModelAdmin.change_list_template Path to a custom template, used by
> changelist_view().
>
> ModelAdmin.delete_confirmation_template Path to a custom template,
> used by delete_view() for displaying a confirmation page when deleting
> one or more objects.
>
> ModelAdmin.delete_selected_confirmation_template Path to a custom
> template, used by the delete_selected action method for displaying a
> confirmation page when deleting one or more objects. See the actions
> documentation.
>
> ModelAdmin.object_history_template Path to a custom template, used by
> history_view().

### You can also override admin views entirely

The admin view is just a django view. You can override it entirely from rendering to context by overriding the following methods:

> ModelAdmin.add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None)
> Django view for the model instance addition page. See note below.
>
> ModelAdmin.change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='',
> extra_context=None) Django view for the model instance edition page.
> See note below.
>
> ModelAdmin.changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None) Django
> view for the model instances change list/actions page. See note below.
>
> ModelAdmin.delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None)
> Django view for the model instance(s) deletion confirmation page. See
> note below.
>
> ModelAdmin.history_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None)

Comment: You can also create a custom widget or extend a existing one with some html. Maybe in combination with a custom model field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: @allcaps, good point! Added. If it's to be reused, I'm all for custom widgets!

Comment: The link provided in the above comment is for a custom model field. The docs on widgets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/